# Creating aggregators in rpivotTable

Tags: r, pivottable.js, rpivottable

I'm starting to use the `rpivotTable` function:

```
library(rpivotTable)
rpivotTable(mtcars, rows="gear", col="cyl", aggregatorName="Average", 
vals="mpg", rendererName="Bar Chart")
```

With this code I have the average mpg by cyl and gear. What if I would like compute the weighted average mpg with hp? I should create my aggregator! I read [here](https://github.com/nicolaskruchten/pivottable/wiki/Aggregators) that it's possible. But how then pass it to R ?

Comment: Sorry for the long delay ;). I'm the creator of the package (on top of the marvellous work of the creator of `pivottable.JS`).  Thanks for using `rpivotTable`.  While in JavaScript it make sense to use custom aggregators, in `R` you can simply add a column with the `weighted average mpg with hp`.